# How to maintain developer and production composer in one file?

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

So I am developing both my project and several libraries at the same time. This means that my libraries have both local versions I am using, and also canonincal versions on the network.

My intention is to be able to leverage this composer file for local development, and also use it such that my deploy pipeline runs "composer install" and we're good. However, fresh installs of a particular app do no usually have local versions of the app available in the folder above.

Would love to know how to best approach this.

This is what it looks like in my composer.json right now:

```
"repositories": [
{
    "type": "path",
    "url": "../my-data-access-layer"
},
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://fossil.mydomain.com/my-data-access-layer"
},
```

],
"require": {
"mucholove/my-data-access-layer": "*"
}